# tcl tcltest unknown option -run

Tags: testing, tcl

When I run ANY test I get the same message. Here is an example test:

```
package require tcltest
namespace import -force ::tcltest::*
test foo-1.1 {save 1 in variable name foo} {} {
    set foo 1
} {1}
```

I get the following output:

```
WARNING: unknown option -run: should be one of -asidefromdir, -constraints, -debug, -errfile, -file, -limitconstraints, -load, -loadfile, -match, -notfile, -outfile, -preservecore, -relateddir, -singleproc, -skip, -testdir, -tmpdir, or -verbose
```

I've tried multiple tests and nothing seems to work. Does anyone know how to get this working?

**Update #1:**

The above error was my fault, it was due to it being run in my script. However if I run the following at a command line I got no output:

```
[root@server1 ~]$ tcl
tcl>package require tcltest
2.3.3
tcl>namespace import -force ::tcltest::*
tcl>test foo-1.1 {save 1 in variable name foo} {expr 1+1} {2}
tcl>echo [test foo-1.1 {save 1 in variable name foo} {expr 1+1} {2}]

tcl>
```

How do I get it to output pass or fail?

Comment: I can't reproduce this from the example. Could there be a stray `-run` somewhere else in your code?

Comment: I was sending to another proc to eval. that had the -run, I had to remove it from argv `set ::argv [lreplace ::argv 0 0]`. However now there is no output whatsoever

Comment: Not having seen your code, I have absolutely no idea what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't get any output from the `test` command itself (as long as the test passes, as in the example: if it fails, the command prints a "contents of test case" / "actual result" / "expected result" summary; see also the remark on configuration below). The test statistics are saved internally: you can use the `cleanupTests` command to print the Total/Passed/Skipped/Failed numbers (that command also resets the counters and does some cleanup).

(When you run `runAllTests`, it runs test files in child processes, intercepting the output from each file's `cleanupTests` and adding them up to a grand total.)

The internal statistics collected during testing is available in AFACT undocumented namespace variables like `::tcltest::numTests`. If you want to work with the statistics yourself, you can access them **before** calling `cleanupTests`, e.g.

```
parray ::tcltest::numTests
array set myTestData [array get ::tcltest::numTests]
set passed $::tcltest::numTests(Passed)
```

Look at the source for `tcltest` in your library to see what variables are available.

The amount of output from the `test` command is configurable, and you can get output even when the test passes if you add `p` / `pass` to the `-verbose` option. This option can also let you have less output on failure, etc.

You can also create a command called `::tcltest::ReportToMaster` which, if it exists, will be called by `cleanupTests` with the pertinent data as arguments. Doing so seems to suppress both output of statistics and at least most resetting and cleanup. (I didn't go very far in investigating that method.) Be aware that messing about with this is more likely to create trouble than solve problems, but if you are writing your own testing software based on `tcltest` you might still want to look at it.

Oh, and please use the newer syntax for the `test` command. It's more verbose, but you'll thank yourself later on if you get started with it.

Obligatory-but-fairly-useless (in this case) documentation link: [tcltest](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/tcltest.htm)

Comment: Thank you, i prints out now. You say it returns it as a string but when i do `set u [cleanupTests];puts $u` the $u variable is an empty string. Is there a way to get the ouput into a variable?

Comment: The `test` command produces _plenty_ of output if the test fails. It's just quiet if it all worked…

Comment: `::tcltest::ReportToMaster` is used for handling where tests are being run in a sub-interpreter. It's part of how tcltest works, and should not be changed by hand.

Comment: @DonalFellows: thanks for correcting me. I was talking about the code in the example, but I should of course have mentioned that it's another matter if the test fails.

Comment: Thanks guys. Im using the array, and running the tests by exec'ing a different script so that i can capture output (when there are errors). Would be nice if this had the option to return an object OR print output.